# Relative element exceeds viewport

Tags: css

I am working on somebody else's code so the only thing I can change is CSS.
I have something similar to this for the html :

```
<div class="myElement">
...
   <div class="menu">
      <div class="menuList"></div>
   </div>
...
</div>
```

- myElement : it is the element i don't want to exceed and it can simply be the view port. I don't want it to be scrollable
- menu : its position is absolute
- menulist: its position is relative and its max-height is 300px but I want the max height to change in order to not exceed its great-parent

The objective is that i don't want the menuList to exceed 300px but I also don't want it to exceed the viewport or the myElement.

I would love a solution like this :

```
.menuList{
     max-height: calc(100% - (offset-top));
}
```

Hope you have a solution for this one !

Answer (score 0):

This example simulates

- if `myElement` was shorter than the `menuList`, and
- if `menuList` was taller than 300px.
- `menu` is also absolutely positioned

Setting `overflow` to `auto` alongside a height limit tests that when the content causes it to grow tall, it will use scroll bars. If it's shorter though, the scrollbars will disappear. Same behaviour for `menu` as well.

```css
.myElement {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.myElement .menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}

.myElement .menu .menuList {
  max-height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement">
   <div class="menu">
      <div class="menuList">
        <ul>        
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
          <li>Four</li>
          <li>Five</li>
          <li>Six</li>
          <li>Seven</li>
          <li>Eight</li>
          <li>Nine</li>
          <li>Ten</li>
          <li>Eleven</li>
          <li>Twelve</li>
          <li>Thirteen</li>
          <li>Fourteen</li>
          <li>Fifteen</li>
          <li>Sixteen</li>
          <li>Seventeen</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed my question and added more informations : i don't want overflow I want a height adaptation. My problem is that sometime my menu is at the middle of the screen (so no problem) and sometime it is at the bottom (so the max-height should be smaller)